# What client-side changes have to be made to migrate over from ActiveMQ Classic to ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

Purely looking client-side at [the migration guide](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/migration), I didn't see anything in particular with respect to client-side changes that are required.

Do I need to change anything client-side to support ActiveMQ Artemis? For example is it required that I use `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` vs. using `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` if I am connecting to an ActiveMQ Artemis broker? Is there anything else not mentioned directly in the guide that needs to change?

For context, I'd like to migrate over everyone to use Artemis but have some sort of toggle to switch between instantiating an Artemis broker vs. a classic broker, and I'm wondering how well I can do this without exposing these details to the clients (i.e. do they need to know about the toggle?). Ideally I could gradually shift over the broker instances to run Artemis without changing any of the client-side configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't *required* to change anything on the client because ActiveMQ Artemis supports the OpenWire protocol used by the JMS client shipped with ActiveMQ Classic.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a difference in using the new ActiveMQConnectionFactory in Artemis vs the old one (if I only use methods available in the classic API)?

Comment: This is wider subject that should be answered in its own question.

Comment: Fair enough, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77822839/is-there-a-difference-in-using-the-new-activemqconnectionfactory-in-artemis-vs-t