# Is there a difference in using the JMS ConnectionFactory from ActiveMQ Artemis vs from ActiveMQ Classic?

Tags: activemq-artemis

There is a `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` and a `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`. If I am upgrading to an ActiveMQ Artemis broker, my understanding is that I don't necessarily have to upgrade clients to use the Artemis factory (classic will work) based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77817981/3813411) question. But what advantages does the new class have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JMS implementations shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis and ActiveMQ Classic are 100% different so there are *lots* of differences in the details, but I'll focus on the broad differences here...

The ActiveMQ Artemis JMS client fully implements JMS 1.1, 2.0 as well as Jakarta Messaging 3.0 & 3.1. It uses the "core" protocol which has a very compact wire format and was designed for high performance. It provides a client-side JNDI implementation. It can only be used with ActiveMQ Artemis.

ActiveMQ Classic JMS client only fully implements JMS 1.1 and *partially* implements JMS 2.0 and Jakarta Messaging 3.0 & 3.1. It uses the "OpenWire" protocol. It also provides a client-side JNDI implementation. It can be used with ActiveMQ Classic and ActiveMQ Artemis.